# redirect from application(on root domain level) to subapplication

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

My hosting supports only web.config IIS configuration. I want to redirect my

http://domain -> http://domain/X

and here is my try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://domain/X/" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

it works, but the trouble it works for all sites and when I already on http://domain/X/ it still working so I'm getting recursion http://domain/X/X/X/X/X/X/X etc...

Temporary solution is to put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false"  />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

into http://domain/X and http://domain/Y etc... but when I go to the http://domain/Y/Z it anyways redirects me to http://domain/X/Z/ (so hell I don't really want to put this in any folder)

So I think I need to fix first redirection (Somehow) to make it works only for http://domain/

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `childOnly` attribute - as per [documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect), this would redirect only if the file name is present in the url. So only urls of form `http://domain/<file name>` would get redirected to `http://domain/X/<file name>` and that should solve your issue. For redirecting `http://domain/`, you may use a default document redirecting to `http://domain/X`.

You may also look at URL Rewrite module - see http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/ (but of course, it will not issue HTTP redirects if that is the need)

Comment: I added childOnly="true" but result is still the same: http://domain/Y/Z it anyways redirects me to http://domain/X/Z/ - that's wrong for me, I want only domain/ redirects to domain/X and being able to work with domain/Y as well.